# Merging PHP IF statements to a single statement or function

Tags: php

So I have some code that it seems that I have to repeat over and over again for $round == P,1,2 and A. Is there any I can achieve this without producing redundant code?

I'm thinking of writing a function that simply swaps through through all 3 possible $round variables that can be available and echoing the relevant information. Any idea on how to achieve this?

The other information will remain the same - its only $round that will change,

```
// determine previous round

      if($round == "P") echo "";

            // if we are in round 1, look up round P bookings

            if($round == "1")
            { 
      $sql = "SELECT 
                            *
                            FROM ts_request
                            INNER JOIN ts_day
                            ON ts_request.day_id = ts_day.id
                            INNER JOIN ts_period
                            ON ts_request.period_id = ts_period.id
                            INNER JOIN ts_allocation
                            ON ts_request.id = ts_allocation.request_id
                            WHERE ts_request.round=:round
                            AND ts_request.dept_id=:dept
                            ORDER BY ts_request.module_id ASC";

            $stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
            $stm->execute( array( ':round' => 'P', ':dept' => $loggedin_id  ) );
            $rows = $stm->fetchAll();   

      foreach ($rows as $row) 
            {               
            echo '<tr align="center">'; 
            echo '<td>'.$row['module_id'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$row['day'].'</td>';    
            echo '<td>'.$row['period'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>';

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ts_roompref
                                WHERE request_id=:id";
                $stm = $pdo->prepare( $sql );
                $stm->execute( array( ':id' => $row['request_id']) );
                $rows2 = $stm->fetchAll();                  

                foreach ($rows2 as $row2) 
                {               
                        if ($row2['room_id']=="0")
                        {
                            echo "Any<br>";
                        }
                            else
                        {
                            echo $row2['room_id'].'<br>';
                        }   
                }

            echo '</td>';           
            echo '<td>'.$row['status'].'</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            }
            }

            // if we are in round 2, look up round 1 bookings

            if($round == "2")
            { 
      $sql .= "";
            }   
      foreach ($rows as $row) 
            {
            // echo results here
            };

            // if we are in round A, look up round 2 bookings

            if($round == "A")
            { 
      $sql .= "";
            }           
      foreach ($rows as $row) 
            {

            // echo results here

            };
```

Comment: `$round` vs. `$rounds` different variables?

Comment: @michi Sorry they are the same. Must have been a typo!

Comment: Amusing note: a DB Admin who is debugging queries in a log will probably wonder who put all that whitespace in their queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help.

```
$roundsInOrder = array('P', '1', '2', 'A');
$roundKey = array_search($incomingRoundLetter, $roundsInOrder);
if ($roundKey !== false || $roundKey != 0) { 
    $roundToQuery = $roundsInOrder[$roundKey - 1];
    // your other code snipped
    $stm->execute( array( ':round' => $roundToQuery, ':dept' => $loggedin_id  ) );
    //more code here
}
```

What this code does:

It sets up the rounds in order.  Then, it searches the rounds for the incoming round.  We really want the key.  Then, the if statement checks to a) make sure we have actually found the round and b) the round is not the first one (0 = P) because we don't want to do any query then.  Finally, the $roundToQuery gets the value out of the rounds that is directly before the current key.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are searching for is the switch() function in php.

Here is a nice and simple tutorial on how to use it:
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/switch.php

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

"Swapping" already exists, it's called "switch statement". In your case it should look like this:

```
switch($round) {
    case "P": 
        //code
    break;


    case "1": 
        //code
    break;


    case "2": 
        //code
    break;


    case "A": 
        //code
    break;


    default: 
        //code, when value of $round doesn't match any case
    break;

}
```

Comment: The code for each case will be the same. Is this really the best way of doing this?

Comment: You mean for `$round == "P"`, `$round == "1"`, `$round == "2"`, `$round == "A"` the code looks the same?

Comment: Yeah its only the $round variable that changes each time because a different set of rows is being pulled from the DB

Comment: @methuselah: use bind with $round before execute.

Comment: `$stm->execute( array( ':round' => $round, ':dept' => $loggedin_id  ) );` should work if I understand you correctly.